# Can't use bars | | in nomenclature package

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

Here's a weird error that I'm running into using the nomenclature package `nomencl`

The following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$S^n$}{The $n$-sphere defined by $S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \  |x| = 1 \}$}
\nomenclature{$\mathbb{Z}$}{The integers}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

gives the following output

[image]

However if in the above I change

```
$S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \text{norm of } x = 1 \}$
```

to

```
$S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \  |x| = 1 \}$
```

so that I have the following (desired) code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$S^n$}{The $n$-sphere defined by $S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \  |x| = 1 \}$}
\nomenclature{$\mathbb{Z}$}{The integers}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

then the part about the n-sphere doesn't show up anymore

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm using the nomenclature package outside of its scope, but it seems to be that the character

```
|
```

doesn't work in math mode when used in the second input of `\nomenclature{}{}`. How can I get the desired code to compile/render correctly?

For what it's worth I am using pdfLatex to render the output.

Comment: @c.p. I just tried it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Isn't nomenclature using makeindex behind the scenes? There | is a special char. Use `\vert` instead. Btw `|` is not the correct symbol for absolute value or norm, try taking the norm of `-1` and you'll notice the spacing on the minus is wrong. I generally recommend using a `\abs` macro etc, see the examples in the mathtools manual

Comment: A recommended way for sets is `\{x\in X \mid <conditions>\}`; using “space,bar,space” is wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The character `|` is special for MakeIndex, so entries with it are rejected. You could quote it, but `nomencl.ist` defines the quoting character as `%`, so the effect is that no quoting character is available at all.

On the other hand, the correct syntax for your set notation and the absolute value is

```
\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid \lvert x\rvert = 1 \}
```

which poses no problem to `nomencl`.

This is how I'd code the example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nomencl}

% shorthands
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}% generic command
\newcommand{\nR}{\numberset{R}}
\newcommand{\nZ}{\numberset{Z}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

% setup

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\mbox{}

\nomenclature[Sn]{$S^n$}{The $n$-sphere defined by $S^n = \{x \in \nR^{n+1} \mid \abs{x} = 1 \}$}
\nomenclature[Z]{$\nZ$}{The integers}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Using the prefix for `\nomenclature` helps in sorting. The shorthands help in keying and reading the source.

[image]